# Ruby : Net::HTTP parse adds %0A at end

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to open a file called test.txt and then import each line in a variable called 'line' and then add it in url file to make request.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

puts "Enter URL :-"
gurl = gets.chomp

total = File.foreach('test.txt').count
c=0

while(c < total)
line = IO.readlines("test.txt")[c]
aurl = "#{gurl}/#{line}"
encoded_url = URI.encode(aurl)
url = URI.parse(encoded_url)
puts "\n #{url} \n"
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
puts "\n Response received for #{line} => #{res.code} \n"
c+=1
end
```

Sample outpute =>

```
 http://www.example.com/z.php%0A

 Response received for z.php
 => 404

 http://www.example.com/index.php%0A

 Response received for index.php
 => 404
```

Anyway to escape %0A (Newline) ?
All new to ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test.txt` has n lines, you read it n+1 times!

Here's a modified version, which chomp to remove the newline/linefeed character :

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

puts "Enter URL :-"
gurl = gets.chomp

File.foreach('test.txt') do |line|
  line.chomp!
  aurl = "#{gurl}/#{line}"
  encoded_url = URI.encode(aurl)
  url = URI.parse(encoded_url)
  puts "\n #{url} \n"
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
  puts "\n Response received for #{line} => #{res.code} \n"
end
```

Comment: i already solved the problem,  but this worked perfectly too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the newline by using [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
line = IO.readlines("test.txt")[c].chomp
```